# Undecidable if TM overwrites its input?

Tags: decidable

I came across a statement postulating that it's undecidable whether a TM overwrites any of its own input.

What would be intuition as well as an actual proof for that?

Comment: As for an actual proof, I'm too far away from college for that. But intuitively, here goes. The tape is the only real source of what you could call persistent memory. So to track if something was overwritten, you'd need to save the original value along with some formulation of how to match that value with the cell it belongs to. The tape can be infinite, so you couldn't store the original values for all possible inputs. And you can't get clever and say there are infinite many states and store it that way, because the number of states are finite. Hope that helps (and is correct or makes sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROOF:

Build a machine `B` that takes as input a machine `A`, and simulates it without disturbing the input string (the string describing `A`). This is not difficult.

Now build machine `C`, a modified version of `B`. If `A` ever halts, `C` will overwrite the input string; until then it will leave the input string untouched.

In order to decide whether `C` (acting on `A`) ever overwrites its input string, one must decide whether `A` ever halts. But "does `A` halt" is undecidable, therefore so is "does `C` overwrite its input".

INTUITION:

With Turing machines, almost anything that isn't easy is impossible.

Comment: I am a little confused why we need machine B. If B is equivalent to A, can't we just say "C is a modified version of A" instead of  "C is a modified version of B"?

Comment: I described B to illustrate the idea of what it does. It takes an input string describing the machine A, then simulates A without ever disturbing that input string. C is *not* a modified version of A; it takes A as input.